# Why is JavaScript code written so it is almost deliberately hard to read?

Tags: javascript, formatting

I've been doing some maintenance work on a few sites (all originally developed by different people) and I have noticed a lot of JavaScript code like this:

```
function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}
```

A few minutes of effort can improve the readability.

```
function MM_findObj(name)
{
    var doc = document;
    var x;

    if((var p = name.indexOf("?")) > 0 && parent.frames.length != 0)
    {
        doc = parent.frames[name.substring(p + 1)].document;
        name = name.substring(0, p);
    }

    if(!(x = doc[name]) && doc.all)
    {
        x = doc.all[name];
    }

    for (var i = 0; !x && i < doc.forms.length; i++)
    {
        x = doc.forms[i][name];
    }

    for(var i = 0; !x && doc.layers && i < doc.layers.length; i++)
    {
        x = MM_findObj(name, doc.layers[i].document);
    }

    if(!x && doc.getElementById)
    {
        x = doc.getElementById(name);
    }

    return x;
}
```

I am curious as to why JavaScript tends not to be written in a readable way? Of the sites that I have worked on - and have had nothing to do with the initial development - condensed, poorly formatted and unreadable JavaScript is definitely a trend I have noticed. Is it merely to reduce the amount of space that scripts take up on pages or is it just poor technique?

Edit: To add to this question, why does single character variable names also seem to be the norm?

P.S. By no means am I an expert, in fact I am barely proficient, with JavaScript so if anybody could also explain what the above code actually *does* then it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: To reduce the few minutes of effort to one second of effort, use http://jsbeautifier.org/. Correction: 15 seconds of effort (in this case) because you have to add braces manually and rebeautify

Comment: Aside from minification, that might be some of the awful code spit out by Dreamweaver or something like that.

Comment: You may find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763458/how-to-optimally-serve-and-load-javascript-files/) interesting reading.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are very commonly-used [tools](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) that take JavaScript code and remove unneeded whitespace and shorten variable names, producing code like this, or worse. It saves network bandwidth, and keeps casual lookie-loos from reading your code (very poor security by obscurity.)

Normally the code doesn't look like this when people are working on it; this is just done when the code is about to ship.

Comment: So then should it be good practice to keep pre-deployment (i.e. nicely formatted, readable) code in a directory somewhere in the site root for future engineers to refer to when performing maintenance?

Comment: "In a directory somewhere in the site root"?  No.  In the source code control system and/or content management system?  Yes.

Comment: @bobble14988 -- What he said!

Answer (score 3):

Javasicript for web browsers is usually optimized for the browser, not a human reader.  When developing it, you treat it like a compiled language; sure, the source code is nicely formatted, commented, etc., but that's not what you deliver.  The actual artifact has been "minified" to reduce network consumption.  It can make a substantial difference in your bandwidth bill over a few million hits.

So you aren't seeing the code the way the author sees it; you're seeing the moral equivalent of a compiled executable.

Of course, most browsers and servers support automatically gzipping the Javascript in transit, which makes minification rather less necessary than it used to be.  But it's still part of the process for most webdev shops.

Answer (score 2):

compressing JS reduces bandwidth usage and therefore speeds up page load times, although you should only do this on release, not to your source :(

[js beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) will fix it for you automatically

Comment: man it's a shame jsbeautifier doesn't add braces to inline blocks or indent them properly

Answer (score 0):

if you need the readable javascript for learning or building code,use the original version from the original website, don't use the min version, it is hard to read.

then if you want to implementing you javascript code, you can make or use min version to get the best performance in the network. the size of file really difference. i think that is why the programmer release two version of javascript.

You can use tools like [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)  to make minimal javascript.

browser just need the same symbol to running code, not the mean of word in human language.